# Choice model from aggregated dataframe in R

Tags: r, model, aggregation

I would like to fit a choice model to an aggregated dataframe of sales data. I was thinking of using R and the mlogit package to fit a logit model, however that can only be done with data on an individual level.
Is it possible to get to an individual data level in R using an aggregated dataframe?

I would like some guidance onhow to think about this problem...
Am I on the right track?

Below is a reproducible example:

```
library(mlogit)
library(dplyr)
data(Car)
#make a an aggregated dataframe
car2 <- group_by(Car,type1,fuel1,range1) %>% summarise(sales=n())

head(car2)
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: type1, fuel1 [2]

   type1    fuel1 range1 sales
  <fctr>   <fctr>  <dbl> <int>
1 regcar methanol     50   110
2 regcar methanol     75   180
3 regcar methanol    125  1138
4 regcar methanol    200   945
5 regcar      cng     75   307
```

Also, I have found some articles of Bayesian methods for estimating
disaggregate choice models using aggregate data. 
Would be very greatful if someone have some tutorials in R or some code examples to get me started.

Thankful for tips and guidance